# What's the simplest way to turn a UITableView navigation into a sidebar menu?

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView that passes data onto another view, much like the example from http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-passing-data/

...and I want to turn this into a sidebar menu type navigation (like in the facebook app.)

I'm sure there's a great deal of tutorials on sidebars, but I want to know if there's a simple solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple frameworks available on Cocoapods for side bar menus. These are by far the easiest to use as Cocoapods installs them and sets them up in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also needed this functionality in my app, I find this is the easiest and simplest one https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo. you should be able to take your UITableView and place it directly into it without changing much (use the V2 one if you can)

Comment: Another great library is [`IIViewDeckController`](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck).